# write() warning message in compilation

Tags: c, warnings

I have a piece of code to create function to print a message from input parameter.

I've been compiling the code with c9.io and works pretty well without warnings but when i do it locally it shows a warning like this:

> child2bok: c39:11: warning: Ignoring return value of 'write', declares with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused -result]

And this is the code.Sure it is a problem with write() definition but i'm so novice with unix programming and no idea to solve it. It executes well but i'd like to remove the warning before i deliver to the teacher.

Here you are the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "rutines.h"

void children();
void show_help();

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int ord;

    if (argc > 1)
        ord = atoi(argv[1]);
    if (argc == 1)
    {
        show_help("Error"); 
        exit(1);
    }

    children(ord);
}

void children(int ord)
{
    char msg[10];

    srand(getpid());
    sleep(rand() % 5);
    sprintf(msg, " %d", ord);
    while (strlen(msg) > 0)
    {
    int written= write(1, msg, strlen(msg));
    if (written < 0)
    break;

    exit(0);
}

void show_help(char *err_message)
{
    write_string(err_message,"");
    write_string("Usage: child2aok \n","");
}
```

Comment: Additional comment: This code is called with another program with execlp function.

Answer (score 1):

You should check and handle the value returned by the `write()` command. From the `write` documentation:

> write [...] may return less than count even under valid conditions.

Why don't you simply use `printf(" %d", ord);` instead of `sprintf(msg, " %d", ord); write(1, msg, strlen(msg))`?

Comment: printf is not a substitute for write, it is a rather large function compared to a really small syscall, it is typically acceptable to simply prepend write with a (void) (as well as other int type functions where you are not concerned with the return value) ... that being said, a robust application would use the return value to verify the full data is written; however I have yet to see a write() fail as long as the file descriptor was valid.  Besides printf has the same return type issues.

Comment: @technosaurus: I see no reason to use `sprintf/write` instead of `printf`. That being said: if you read the documentation of `write` you will see that it can return nonzero even if the command does not fail. So with write you *must* check the return code, with printf you don't have to.

Comment: Both write and printf return the number bytes written, a zero return is not "success" (see kerrek's answer).  snprintf is also unnecessary, you can just itoa() a string for writing.

Comment: @technosaurus: kerrek's is saying the same I'm saying. You shouldn't use write without checking the return value. Instead you could use printf without checking the return value. You should trust the developers of the library who marked that function to emit a warning if you don't check the return value. Anyway, as a principle, it is *always* a bad idea to mask a warning if you are not 100% sure of what you are doing. The solution of kerrek is ok, but much more simple and clearer would be to replace sprintf/write with printf.

Answer (score 0):

`write` does not guarantee to write all the data; it may write as little as *one* byte (or block, or return an error, ...). So you have to use it in a *loop*:

```
bool write_all(int fd, void * buf, size_t len)
{
    size_t remaining = len;

    for (size_t n; (n = write(fd, buf, remaining)) > 0; remaining -= n)
    { }

    return remaining == 0;
}
```

This function returns `true` if all bytes were written, and `false` on error.